# Does CSS mix-blend-mode work with transform?

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

Apparently mix-blend-mode doesn't play nice with `transform: translate()` and `z-index`. Applying any of these to some text element will immediately cancel the mix-blend-mode affect.

**Questions**

1. Is this a known limitation?
2. Is there a CSS-based workaround?

I know I can use JavaScript to mimic the `transform: translate()` functionality, but this isn't really ideal.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in Chrome and not in Firefox.

Comment: Still having issues in chrome but not firefox

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and the workaround I found was replacing `transform: translate()` by `position:absolute`, `margin-top:<y>px` and `margin-left:<x>px`.

NB: Negative margins are valid so it still works with negative `x` and `y`.