# mix-blend-mode stops working when I use transform property

Tags: css, css-transforms, mix-blend-mode

So when I use mix-blend-mode with transform property, mix-blend-mode stops working. Is there a work around? I know this is a duplicate question of [Does CSS mix-blend-mode work with transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369298/does-css-mix-blend-mode-work-with-transform) but the mentioned question doesn't have an answer.

Codepen (GSAP may not work in the snippet):

https://codepen.io/bimalpandeycode/pen/vYWZvao?editors=1111

```js
let hasHovered = false;
const mouseEnterGSAP = () => {
  console.log("ENTER");
  hasHovered = true;
  gsap.to(".cursor", {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  });
}
const mouseLeveGSAP = () => {
  hasHovered = false;
  gsap.to(".cursor", {
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
  });
}
const cursor = document.getElementById("cursor");
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  cursor.setAttribute("style", `left:${e.pageX}px; top:${e.pageY}px; width:${hasHovered?"100px":"0px"} height:${hasHovered?"100px":"0px"}`);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.cursor {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 2;
}

.skills__text__container__Main__langs {
  color: cyan;
}

.first {
  transform: skewX(20deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/CSSRulePlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/CustomBounce3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/CustomEase3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/CustomWiggle3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/DrawSVGPlugin3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/Draggable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/EaselPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/EasePack.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/Flip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/GSDevTools3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/InertiaPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MorphSVGPlugin3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/MotionPathHelper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/MotionPathPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/Physics2DPlugin3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/PhysicsPropsPlugin3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/PixiPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/ScrambleTextPlugin3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/SplitText3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/TextPlugin.min.js"></script>




<div id="cursor" class="cursor"></div>
<div class="skills__text__container__Main__langs" onMouseEnter="mouseEnterGSAP()" onMouseLeave="mouseLeveGSAP()">
  <div class="skills__text__container__Main__langs__1">
    <div class="first">HTML/+4</div>
    <div class="a10">Nodejs/+2</div>
    <div class="a20">GSAP/+2</div>
    <div class="a30">SASS/+2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="skills__text__container__Main__langs__2">
    <div class="a01">JavaScript/+4</div>
    <div class="a11">ExpressJs/+2</div>
    <div class="a21">UNITY/C#/+2</div>
    <div class="a31">GIMP/+2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="skills__text__container__Main__langs__3">
    <div class="a02">CSS/+4</div>
    <div class="a12">SQL/+2</div>
    <div class="a22">Figma/+2</div>
    <div class="a32">TypeScript
      <1</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add code so we can see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: But it is still a duplicate.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it's a duplicate to a certain extent, but the earlier question is general - and thus I suppose doesn't need to have example code - whereas this one could be made more specific as the OP is talking about 'when I use mix-blend-mode with transform property' and I was hoping some code of the specific problem could help find a solution for their specific problem. The earlier question has no answer, and only very slight and not very deep discussion. Just marking  this as duplicate will pretty much ensure it never gets answered or even properly discussed/explained.

Comment: I'm trying to recreate it in codepen, give me a minute.<3

Comment: @AHaworth that's exactly the reason I still have not marked it as a duplicate. In the hope it attracts an answerer. We can always close the other one if this gets answered - or vice-versa.

Comment: https://codepen.io/bimalpandeycode/pen/vYWZvao?editors=1111 This is the example, it somehow works on codepen but I tried it in both firefox and chrome, it didn't work. On my local machine whenever that class ".first" has transform:skewX(); , mix-blend-mode doesn't work but when I comment that css line out, it works.

Answer (score -1):

OP-
adding z-index to the div with mix-blend-mode fixed it.
I found the answer in https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/mix-blend-mode-conundrum/209068/4 forum

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).