# How can I make my text visible when my custom curser hovers over it

Tags: javascript, css, cursor

I have a circle that follows my cursor. I was wondering if I can add an effect so when the circle hovers over the text it turns only the text under the circle to black so you are able to see the text even when the white circle is on top of it.

I tried to make the text black when I hover over it using CSS but it wont work when the words are too big because the text out of the circle contrast with the background.

I want only the text under the circle to turn black and the rest of it outside of the circle to remain white. like if the circle is over the "hel" in "hello world" I want the "hel" to be black and the "lo world" to be white

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const interBubble = document.getElementById('circle');
  let curX = 0;
  let curY = 0;
  let tgX = 0;
  let tgY = 0;

  function move() {
    curX += (tgX - curX) / 10;
    curY += (tgY - curY) / 10;
    interBubble.style.transform = `translate(${Math.round(curX)}px, ${Math.round(curY)}px)`;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      move();
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    tgX = e.clientX;
    tgY = e.clientY;

    if (e.target.tagName === 'P' ||
      e.target.tagName === 'A' ||
      e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON' ||
      e.target.parentNode.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
      interBubble.classList.add('big');
    } else {
      interBubble.classList.remove('big');
    }
  });

  move();
});
```

```css
Body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20%;
  z-index: 2;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

p:hover {
  color: black;
}

:root {
  --trans-bounce: cubic-bezier(.4,2.2,.6,1.0);
  --trans-time: .4s;
}

.mouseFollowCircle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
  background-color: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: width var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), height var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), top var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), left var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), background-color var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce);
}

.mouseFollowCircle.big {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -35px;
  left: -35px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
  background-color: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: width var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), height var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), top var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), left var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), background-color var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce);
}
```

```html
<div><p>X</p><p>Hello World</p></div>
<section class="mouseFollowCircle" id="circle"></section>
```

Comment: `p { color: black;`?

Comment: Have you looked into mix-blend-mode?

Comment: I would want it to only effect the text. is it possible for it to only effect the text and nothing else?

Comment: It affects colors e.g. white on white difference would make black and white on black would make white. If your real situation is more complex than you have shown in terms of 'nothing else' please give a more complete snippet.

Comment: Am I right in thinking the change in your question you have just made is to have a linear background gradient rather than plain black? If so, what color do you want the circle to be when hovering over the text? Is it to remain white?

Comment: Yeah the circle will remain white while the text goes black when it’s over it

Answer (score 2):

`mix-blend-mode: difference` will change white on white to black and white on black will be white.

However, the two elements have to be at the same level so z-index and transforms are removed in this snippet. The transform property is replaced by margin-top and -left (thanks to this [Does CSS mix-blend-mode work with transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369298/does-css-mix-blend-mode-work-with-transform))

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const interBubble = document.getElementById('circle');
  let curX = 0;
  let curY = 0;
  let tgX = 0;
  let tgY = 0;

  function move() {
    curX += (tgX - curX) / 10;
    curY += (tgY - curY) / 10;
    //interBubble.style.transform = `translate(${Math.round(curX)}px, ${Math.round(curY)}px)`;
    interBubble.style.marginTop = `${Math.round(curY)}px`;
    interBubble.style.marginLeft = `${Math.round(curX)}px`;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      move();
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    tgX = e.clientX;
    tgY = e.clientY;

    if (e.target.tagName === 'P' ||
      e.target.tagName === 'A' ||
      e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON' ||
      e.target.parentNode.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
      interBubble.classList.add('big');
    } else {
      interBubble.classList.remove('big');
    }
  });

  move();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

:root {
  --trans-bounce: cubic-bezier(.4, 2.2, .6, 1.0);
  --trans-time: .4s;
}

.mouseFollowCircle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
  background-color: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  /*backdrop-filter: blur(2px);*/
  transition: width var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), height var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), top var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), left var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), background-color var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce);
}

.mouseFollowCircle.big {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  left: -35px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
  background-color: white;
  pointer-events: none;
  /*backdrop-filter: blur(2px);*/
  transition: width var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), height var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), top var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), left var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce), background-color var(--trans-time) var(--trans-bounce);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<section class="mouseFollowCircle" id="circle"></section>
```

Note I commented out the filter as I wasn't sure you wanted blurry text.

UPDate: the original question had a black background for which this answer works. The question has changed to have a gradient background for which this answer doesn’t work as the white circle picks up color.

Comment: I want it like what you've shown but I need it to work with any colour background